# DevFabric equivalent of ApplicaiontHosts.config?

Tags: iis, web-applications, azure, hostname, azure-compute-emulator

I am testing OAuth with local application hosted on dev fabric.

I want to bind a particular hostname to my local application, usually on IISExpress I would edit the following element in ApplicaiontHosts.config

```
        <site name="BasicChat" id="15">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\xxx.yyy_VAIO\Downloads\Samples-master\Samples-master\BasicChat" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44914:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

What would be the equivalent when I'm testing on DevFabric? How can I alias the call to localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ServiceDefinition.csdef.

Add the hostheader attribute eg:

```
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="xxx" hostHeader="my.yyy.com" />
    </Bindings>
```